# How to build APK in android for java and native c/c++ code

Tags: android

This is my first experience to build an APK for native code in android.when I build APK as we do in android for java code it consists of only Java code ,functionality that implemented in c/c++ not reflected in build when I install apk on device.

Please guide me on the same !!!

Comment: just go through the [Android-NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Android-NDK

[**Android NDK**](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

The **NDK** is a toolset that allows you to implement parts of your app using native-code languages such as `C` and `C++`. For certain types of apps, this can be helpful so that you may reuse existing code libraries written in these languages and possibly increased performance.

Comment: Please tell me the steps how to achieve this using NDK.It would be really helpful for me !!!

Comment: Look at http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/ and http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Comment: This link explain how to develop c/C++ code using NDK and cygwin in android.I want to build third party signed APK to install app on client device.How I achieve this ???